# Uncaught Syntax Error: Unexpected token ILLEGAL With XML & Javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, blogger

I added this code to my blogger template, but it doesn't work and leaves this error in my Chrome console.

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

It indicates the error is here:

```
<div id='slides'>
    <script type='text/javascript'>document.write(&quot;&lt;script src=\&quot;/feeds/posts/default/-/<data:content/>?max-results=&quot;+numposts1+&quot;&amp;orderby=published&amp;alt=json-in-script&amp;callback=showrecentposts1\&quot;&gt;&lt;\/script&gt;&quot;);</script>                     
</div>
<div id='slider_nav'>       
    <script type='text/javascript'>document.write(&quot;&lt;script src=\&quot;/feeds/posts/default/-/<data:content/>?max-results=&quot;+numposts1+&quot;&amp;orderby=published&amp;alt=json-in-script&amp;callback=showrecentposts1a\&quot;&gt;&lt;\/script&gt;&quot;);</script>
</div>
```

I think the problem is pin-pointed here: `<data:content/>`

However, this script works fine in other templates, but not in mine. I'm using the exact same script, and I don't understand why it isn't working.

I've tried replacing the `<data:content/>` with `"+label1+"` which is what I want to do in the end result anyway, I just wanted to get it to work first. When I try adding the label variable, it throw this error in my console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Any help with this?

Comment: Do you really have `&quot;&lt;s...`? That explains your error.

Comment: @bfavaretto it doesn't cause a problem in other templates.

Comment: @bfavaretto if I use '<' instead of '&#lt;' blogger throws a XML parse error.